# How to ignore erros with Pycodestyle and pycodestyle_magic?

Tags: python, pycodestyle

I'm using pycodestyle and pycodestyle_magic, but can't ignore errors.

My code is the following:

```
%pip install flake8 pycodestyle_magic
%load_ext pycodestyle_magic
%pycodestyle_on --ignore E225
a=1
```

I'm expecting no warning, no error.

But here is the result:

```
1:2: E225 missing whitespace around operator
```

This is not what I was expecting.

Technical details:

- pycodestyle==2.8.0
- pycodestyle-magic==0.5
- Python version = 3.8.8

Answer (score 0):

Have you got the `setup.cfg` file? If you do, you can then put there:

```
[pycodestyle]
ignore = E225
```

Comment: I should have explained that I'm doing that through a notebook. It's not possible to use a setup.cfg file;

Comment: Can you use `%flake8 --ignore=E255`?

Comment: Unfortunately, I have a bug with the proposal "%flake8 --ignore=E255".